# Ctrl + l not working on Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

[image]<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on nautilus go to the shows path of the directory. But not working for. How to fix this? Look this image in the previous I press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and next to the home the path bar appear like **/home/**.

Comment: Please consider to edit your question to expand and/or explain better the issue you are having.

Comment: ok I will  edit the question

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? (I'm having the same issue under 14.04)

Comment: @ulmangt I have 14.04 32 bit. But the problem has gone after one restart! also If you have some problems I guess the reason is may be you install some extension on unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the keyboard shortcut under "Go", located just above the arrow in your picture. Check what keyboard shortcut is there for "Enter Location" which is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the shortcut listed for "Enter Location" wasn't practically doing anything. I found I was able to get where I needed to by opening a terminal and entering

`nautilus /home/me/path/to/what/I/want`

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution would be, open your terminal and enter the following command

```
sudo nautilus
```

and close the previous window, now your keyboard shortcut works (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>),
there you go :)

Comment: -1 Super-user privileges have nothing to do with this. Also, you shouldn't run graphical applications with `sudo`. Use `gksudo` or `kdesudo` instead.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Can you back up your statement. I can't think of a reason as to why not

Comment: @SudipBhandari: Ctrl+L toggles the visibility of the address bar in Nautilus. There's no reason whatsoever why a cosmetic change would depend on user privileges. If it did that would be an incredible bug or an insane design decision.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes However that's what's happening even in my ubuntu.. What  could be the reason?

Comment: @SudipBhandari: That's a mystifying yet interesting question. Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster here you go: https://askubuntu.com/questions/914382/file-manager-showing-different-behaviour-when-opened-as-root-and-as-a-normal-use