# File Manager showing different behaviour when opened as root and as a normal user

Tags: 16.04, gnome, nautilus, themes

When I open my file manager on (Ubuntu 16.04, GNOME3 DE) normally as in (`nautilus` or `xdg-open "directory name"` I get a very messed up layout (rendering problem I guess, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> also doesn't work to see/change the path).

[image]

But when I open it as root (`sudo nautilus`) I get a whole different design/look/feel (The one I want to open normally)

[image]

How can this be happening? I want to to able to use the second design. What should I do?

PS: Following is the output

```
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' gnome-shell\* gnome-themes\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p' | xargs -rd'\n' -- apt-cache policy
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
  Candidate: 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.18.5-0ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     3.18.4-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
gnome-shell-common:
  Installed: 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
  Candidate: 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.20.4-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.18.5-0ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
     3.18.4-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
gnome-themes-standard:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.20.2-1ubuntu1~xenial1
  Version table:
     3.20.2-1ubuntu1~xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     3.18.0-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
gnome-themes-standard-data:
  Installed: 3.20.2-1ubuntu1~xenial1
  Candidate: 3.20.2-1ubuntu1~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 3.20.2-1ubuntu1~xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.18.0-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Ubuntu gnome should have second look by default

Comment: This is a theming issue. Could you please either shrink the size of the Nautilus window (so that it isn't maximized) or disable the function that fuses its tool bar to the Gnome Shell status bar? The super-user account doesn't use that theme so it's not affected by the issue.

Comment: @DavidFoerster minimizing didn't change anything.. I am using 'Adwaita' theme. How do I  disable the  function you mention about?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to disable that. I think it's either a Gnome Shell extension or a Gnome Shell Theme. You can try to disable all extensions and switch to a different theme to confirm that. Both can be done with [gnome-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/).

Comment: @DavidFoerster 16.04 tag just doesn't show up for me.. I don't have enough credit to create new tag.. you can go ahead and edit the tag (Thanks!!)

Comment: @DavidFoerster No extensions and tried with all the themes available.. still the same problem (can you suggest me a very compatible theme?)

Comment: You should not use `sudo nautilus`, use `pkexec nautilus` instead.

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main is listed in the output
going with this theme: OSX-Arc-Darker (Display is good)

Comment: Also, it looks like your actual aim is to change the Gnome Shell theme in your regular user account and not to find out why it's different as a super-user. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: @MeganFoxz: I'm not sure how that is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's a theming issue related to the Gnome Staging PPA. Please revert to the stock version of Gnome:

1. Install `ppa-purge`:

   ```
   sudo apt install ppa-purge
   ```
2. Log out of your graphical user session.
3. Switch to a virtual terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and log in there. We're going to replace the graphical environment so let's better not use it while we do that.
4. *Purge* the Gnome Staging PPA:

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
   ```

   This will probably take a while. For more info see [How can PPAs be removed?](/q/307/175814)
5. Reboot.